# centraliser computation of projective linear group in MAGMA

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, magma-cas

I wish to computer the centraliser in $PGL(4,5)$ of $$
[\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}]
$$ using MAGMA.

I found this page which I used to compute it.
[Matrix representation for PGL(n,q) in Magma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2369546/matrix-representation-for-pgln-q-in-magma)

This code gives me a centraliser of order 1488000. I manually found the centraliser as $SL_3(5)\circ_4 C_4$. And this has order 496000. So apparently the central product is missing somehow..

Comment: You can use th function $\mathtt{OrbitAction}$ to get the homomorphism from ${\rm GL}(4,3)$ to ${\rm PGL}(4,3)$.

Comment: Hello Professor Holt! Yes, I found this page of your answer.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2369546/matrix-representation-for-pgln-q-in-magma               But I found the result has a bit of discrepancy of the order of the central product which I calculated by hand...  I am  editing my question.

Comment: Magma is right, your manual calculation is wrong. Your central product should be over $4$, not $3$, and should be $GL$, not $SL$. The centralizer in $GL$ is $GL_3(5)\times C_4$, order 5952000. To get the centralizer in $PGL$ one quotients by the centre, which has order $4$. 5952000/4=1488000.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the input. Am I correct that to get the centralizer in PGL, one cannot simply calculate the preimage in GL and then modulo the center? So I take it in this case, I can do this?

Comment: In general, if $x\in G$ and $N$ is central then $C_G(x)/N$ is not equal to $C_{G/N}(Nx)$. The latter is equal to the set of all elements that conjugate $x$ to $xz$ for some $z\in Z$. In this case, the eigenvalues of $xz$ and $x$ are different, so they cannot be conjugate. Thus you can do this. If the eigenvalues were $1,1,-1,-1$ then you would have to worry.